# Get file names in sharepoint 2013 document library

Tags: document-library, javascript, file

What is the best way to get a list of all the file names in a sharepoint document library with javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there's a property called FileLeafRef, and I could query the library like so...

```
$.ajax({
            url: "site.url/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('LibraryName')/items?$top=1000&$select=FileLeafRef",
            type: "GET",
            headers:
                       {
                           "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                       },
            success: filesuccess,
            error: error
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "site/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents')/Files",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            for(var i = 0; i<data.d.results.length; i++){
                var result data.d.result[i];
            }               
        },
        error: errorListHandler
    });

function errorListHandler(){
    alert('Error!');
}
```

In var result you have information about the file[i] of the array of files

Comment: Including the name of file, URL, Size and more...

Comment: If help mark with answer. Tanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of CAML query to fetch the values as below,

```
var caml = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>
```

Or you can make use of

```
$().SPServices
```

Have a look at the below link,

[Get List items using Jquery](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems)